# Why is the graph of $y=\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(\sum_{x=0}^k\frac{1}{2^x})$ discontinuous?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I noticed some discontinuties in the graph of-

> $$y=\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(\sum_{x=0}^k\frac{1}{2^x})$$

This is what is looks like on the graph-

[image]

Why is the graph discontinuous?I know that functions may be discontinuous if their *value* cannot be determined for a particular value (or it is not defined for that *value* or simply it does not exist).But here,the value of $y$ can be determined for all $x$.

Then why is the graph discontinuous?

Thanks for any help and response!!

Comment: You are using $x$ both for the limiting variable and for the summation variable, which seems a great source of ambiguity.

Comment: @SangchulLee There was a typo...I fixed it...

Comment: Something is very wrong with your understanding of continuity. If a value of $y$ cannot be determined for some $x$, it does **NOT** mean the function is discontinuous. A function can only be discontinuous on points where it *is* defined. e.g. the function $y = \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. But you cannot say it is discontinuous in $x = 0$ because it is not defined there!

Comment: Which variable is on the horizontal axis on the graph? Both $x$ and $k$ are bound ("dummy") variables in the function definition you quote.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is the $X-Y$ plane...Horizontal is $x$,vertical is $y$....

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The graph looks like the graph of $$ f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\operatorname{round}(t)} \frac{1}{2^n} $$ where the "round" function in the upper end of the sum rounds to the nearest integer and _there is no limit involved at all_.

Comment: @tatan: The variable $x$ does not appear free in your defining expression -- it is bound by the sum notation.

Comment: Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\mbox{ if } x\neq 0,\\
1 & \mbox{ if } x=0.
\end{cases}$$ This function has a discontinuity in $x=0$ but is everywhere defined. Try to understand this first. Also, fix your notation, as you have written it down, $y$ is not even a function, but simply the number $2$.

Comment: What you are plotting is a function of $k$, which is discrete, hence the big jumps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$y_k=\sum_{x=0}^k{a^x}$$ It is just a geometric progression which makes $$y_k=\frac{1-a^{k+1}}{1-a}$$ If, as in you case $a=\frac 12$, then $y_k=2-2^{-k}=2-e^{-k\log(2)}$ which would be continuous if $k$ were continuous. Since this is not the case, you need a discrete plot of the following values 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & y_k \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \frac{3}{2} \\
 2 & \frac{7}{4} \\
 3 & \frac{15}{8} \\
 4 & \frac{31}{16} \\
 5 & \frac{63}{32} \\
 6 & \frac{127}{64} \\
 7 & \frac{255}{128} \\
 8 & \frac{511}{256} \\
 9 & \frac{1023}{512} \\
 10 & \frac{2047}{1024}
\end{array}
\right)$$